# Offline installation of R catboost package on ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, catboost

I am working on Azure databricks and it's compute server is Ubuntu 18.04. I want to install [catboost R package](https://catboost.ai/docs/installation/r-installation-local-copy-installation.html) but **without internet access** because of security reasons. I downloaded github repo of catboost on my MacBook that has internet access and zipped it to upload it to Azure for manual installation. I performed following steps:

1. On [catboost installation instructions](https://catboost.ai/docs/installation/r-installation-local-copy-installation.html), `libc6-dev`  is required so I re-installed **build-essential** by downloading it from [this](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-main-amd64/build-essential_12.4ubuntu1_amd64.deb.html) link and uploaded to ubuntu and executed following bash command to make it available: `sudo dpkg -i /dbfs/FileStore/tables/build_essential_12_4ubuntu1_amd64.deb`
2. Using my Macbook (that has internet), I cloned github repo from [here](https://github.com/catboost/catboost) and zipped using MacOS Terminal: `tar czf catboost.tar.gz catboost`
3. I uploaded catboost.tar.gz to Azure and made available in ubuntu
4. I unzipped it on ubuntu and executed build using: `R CMD build /home/catboost_tmp/catboost`
5. After build command, I successfully get a zip file: **catboost_0.26.tar.gz**. I executed following command in R to install catboost:

   **install.packages("catboost_0.26.tar.gz",
   lib = "/databricks/spark/R/lib",
   type = "source",
   repos = NULL,
   verbose = TRUE)**

Installation results in following error:

```
system (cmd0): /usr/lib/R/bin/R CMD INSTALL
* installing *source* package ‘catboost’ ...
** using staged installation
checking for R_HOME... /usr/lib/R
checking for R... /usr/lib/R/bin/R
checking for local CATBOOST_DYNLIB... no
checking whether we can fetch CatBoost dynlib... downloading CatBoost (libcatboostr.so - v0.26)
trying URL 'https://github.com/catboost/catboost/releases/download/v0.26/libcatboostr-linux.so'
Error in download.file(url, dest_fpath, mode = "wb"): cannot open URL 'https://github.com/catboost/catboost/releases/download/v0.26/libcatboostr-linux.so'

Error: Stopping on error
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(url, dest_fpath, mode = "wb") :
  URL 'https://github.com/catboost/catboost/releases/download/v0.26/libcatboostr-linux.so': status was 'Couldn't connect to server'
Execution halted
*** CatBoost dynamic library download failed. stopping.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘catboost’
* removing ‘/databricks/spark/R/lib/catboost’
```

It seems that its trying to connect to github to fetch **libcatboostr-linux.so**, therefore, I created a new environment variable **CATBOOST_DYNLIB** using bash command (`echo "CATBOOST_DYNLIB=/dbfs/FileStore/tables/catboost_pkg/" >> /etc/environment`) and downloaded libcatboostr-linux.so from [here](https://github.com/catboost/catboost/releases/download/v0.26/libcatboostr-linux.so). But I get the same error message!

Any experience developers here who can help me with catboost (R package) installation without access to internet? Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it on my own and here is the solution for others facing similar issues. I was doing it correctly by creating an environment variable **CATBOOST_DYNLIB** but the path should be complete including the file name **libcatboostr-linux.so** . I was only using path to the directory including this file!

Comment: I'll additionally add that, if building it from source through their `ya` make system, this file will be under something like `~/.ya/build/symres<random hash>`.